NM-B wire/ampacity for subpanel - NEC 310.16 and 334.80
An electrician is installing a 100 amp subpanel in my basement approximately 50 feet from the main panel on the opposite side of my house. He is using an 80 amp breaker in the main panel to feed the subpanel. The subpanel will be running a continuous load up to ~60 amps. He ran 4/3 NM-B cable claiming that NM-B cable is not listed in the NEC table 310.16 so the wire can be rated for the 75 degree column, which would allow for up to 85 amps. He also said the while 334.80 says that NM-B must use the ampacity in the 60 degree column he can use 4/3 NM-B for the 80 amp breaker because the 90 degree column can be used or adjustments provided the final amps will not exceed the 60 degree ampacity column, which is 70 amps for 4 gauge wire.
Is the 4/3 NM-B cable the correct size wire or should he use a larger wire?

Breakers protect wires from burning up/causing a fire.  A smaller breaker for the wire and/or panel is good.  A larger breaker for the wire is bad.  You go by breaker protection, not how much amps/power you expect to use, for the size of wire.

The only thing wrong with this is the 80A breaker.  You're planning for about 60A, you're installing 70A cable as you correctly say in your final sentence.  Probably fine. So you need a 70A breaker. (Well the other thing wrong with it is that it is penny-wise.  100A aluminum cable and a 100A breaker would make the subpanel more future-proof.  But that's up to you).
All the other stuff in your question about adjustments is irrelevant to your situation.  (Probably -- is this a high temperature environment?  Sounds like a basement.)
In a high temperature environment you have to adjust the wire's rating downward, and also the breaker.  You're allowed to use the 90° column to make that adjustment, and then only apply it if it is less than the unadjusted 60° rating.  You can't use the higher temp columns for anything else.   Certainly not to create a circuitous (ha ha) argument for using an incorrect breaker.  This 90° leniency is just so you don't get double-whacked for high temperature. So for example if this run is in an attic that gets to 55°C, the adjusted ampacity is 72A (95x.76), so you're still limited to 70A.  The leniency is that you don't have to use the 60° column that would get you an adjusted ampacity of 28A for this wire in your imaginary hot attic.  It does not mean you can use an oversized breaker or take other shortcuts.
